How to use Facebook Graph API for archive ads
I have created a meta developer account to use Graph API but I'm facing restrictions. I want to be able to browser ads relate to a keyword. What are the possible solutions?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
